# Conformal mapping from upper half plane onto upper half plane with deleted slit

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to construct a conformal map from $H= \{z:Im(z)>0\}$ (i.e. the upper half of the complex plane) to $H$ but with a slit removed. The mapping comes up in a paper I'm trying to read.

In particular, fix $\theta \in (0,\pi/2]$ and $p>0$. I'd like to construct $f(z)$, a conformal map that takes $H$ onto $H\setminus \{re^{i\theta}: 0<r\leq p\}$ (i.e. $H$ with the line segment from $0$ to $pe^{i\theta}$ removed). According to the paper, $f$ is not unique as is, so the following conditions are set:

$f(\infty)=\infty$

$f'(\infty)=1$

$f(0)=pe^{i\theta}$.

**What I've done so far:**
I know, for example, that the function $g(z)=i \sqrt{1-z^{2}}$ maps $H$ onto $H$ with a deleted slit from $0$ to $i$. If we look at $g(z)$ as a composition of functions: $-z^{2}$, $1+z$, $\sqrt{z}$, and $iz$, then it's easy to confirm that $0$ is getting "folded into" the new region. In a similar way, I have been trying to find component functions to build $f$, but haven't had any luck yet. I think the thing that is throwing me off is that I want to keep the same boundary along the real axis, but at the same time have the slit inside the region make the angle $\theta$ with the real axis.

Also, I suspect the uniqueness condition on the derivative of $f$ may give important information that I am not picking up on.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The case $\theta=\pi/2$ is not hard, but the general case seems to require the [Schwarz–Christoffel mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping), i.e., an integral representation of the map. Do you actually need a formula or a proof of existence of such a thing?

Comment: The plot thickens... I wasn't aware of the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping and it looks like the way to go. Thanks! I think I have an integral expression, but now the question is whether I'll be able to compute it symbolically or if a numerical method is needed. I guess I'd like either a formula or somewhat detailed information about what the mapping does. Going to mess around with it for a bit more.

Comment: The explicit formula for $\theta=\pi/2$ kind of explains what it does; the general case isn't dramatically different.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an explicit symbolic formula?